# COUNTIF where criterion is a specific sequence of cells

Tags: count, conditional-statements, formula, libreoffice-calc

I'm doing some work with arithmetic sequences modulo P, in which the sequences become periodic under the modulo. My worksheet generates a sequence mod P with the first term being 0, the second term being a number K (referencing another cell), and the following terms following the recurrence relation. The period of the sequence (number of values before it repeats itself) is related to the ratio P/K, s, for example, if P=2 and K=1, I get the sequence {0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,...}, which has a period of 3, so when P/K=2, the period is 3.

I currently have a formula which uses the COUNTIF function to count the number of zeroes in the range, which is then divided out of the total range, currently an arbitrary size of 120, and this gives me the correct period for many ratios of P/K. Most of the time, however, the sequence generated exhibits semi-periodicity and sometimes even quasi-periodicity, such as in the case of K=1 and modulo 9: {0,1,1,2,3,5,8,4,3,7,1,8,0,8,8,7,6,4,1,5,6,2,8,1,...}, where P/K=9, the period is 24, and the semi-period is 12 (because of the 0,8,8,... part of the sequence). In such cases, my current COUNTIF formula thinks the full period is 12, even though it should be 24, because it counts the zeroes which define the semi-period.

What I would like to do is adjust the formula so that instead of the criterion for counting being 0, it would only count triplet sequences of cells in the pattern 0,K,K.

My current formula:

```
=QUOTIENT(120,(COUNTIF(B2:DQ2,0)))
```

So if I have `=QUOTIENT(120,(COUNTIF(B2:DQ2,*X*)))` I want the "*X*", which is currently 0, to reference a *specific* sequence of cells, namely the first three of the overall series, so something like: `=QUOTIENT(120,(COUNTIF(B2:DQ2,(0,C2,D2))))` although obviously that criterion is not in remotely the correct syntax.

I'm not well-versed in writing macros, so that would probably be out of the question.

Comment: Maybe `COUNTIFS(B2:DQ2, X, B2:DQ2, "<>"&0)` ...?

Comment: I'm currently using LIbreOffice, I just figured I'd take whatever people are familiar, since all three are fairly intuitive to move between. I'll update the OP to specify, however. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeeped That returns an error 510. Wouldn't that be counting all the non-zero cells? Basically I just need to count a specific sequence of cells, like every occurrence within the range where only the desired cell values occur in a specific order

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with four helper rows plus the final formula.  Someone more clever than I am might be able to do it in one cell with an array formula; but compared to array formulas I think the helper rows are easier to understand and, if desired, tweak.

Once this is set up, if you're always going to use three as your criterion, you can hide the helper rows (to hide a row, right-click on the gray number label on the left side of the spreadsheet, and choose "hide").

So your sequence is in row 2, starting in column B.  We'll set up the first helper row in row 3, starting in column C.  In cell C3 put the formula `=C2=$B$2`.  This will evaluate to FALSE, which is equivalent to 0.  Copy and paste that formula all the way to cell DQ3 (or however many columns you want to run it).  Cells below a sequence number equal to the first number in the sequence will evaluate to TRUE, which is equivalent to 1.

The next two helper rows are very similar.  In cell D4 put the formula `=D2=$C$2` and copy and paste to cell DQ4.  This row tests which cells are equal to the second number in the sequence.

In cell E5 put the formula `=E2=$D$2` and copy and paste to cell DQ5, showing which cells are equal to the third number in the sequence.

The last helper row is a little different, so I left an empty row after the first three helpers.  In cell E7 I put the formula `=SUM(C3,D4,E5)`; copy and paste that over to column DQ.  This counts how many matches were found in the previous three helper rows.  If all three match, the result of this formula will be 3 and your criterion for determining the period will have been fulfilled.

Now to show the period: in the cell you want to have this number, put the formula `=MATCH(3,E7:DQ7,0)`.  This searches the last (fourth) helper row looking for a cell that is equal to 3.  (Obviously you could modify this method to match only the first two sequence numbers, or to match more than 3, and then you'd adjust the first parameter in the MATCH formula.)  The last parameter in this MATCH formula is 0 because the helper row is not sorted.  The return value is the index of the first match: a match in E7 would be index 1, a match in E8 would be index 2, etc.

I tested this in LibreOffice 4.4.4.3.